# Is it possible to add a methodMissing hook via a category in Groovy?

Tags: java, groovy

I wanted to add the `methodMissing()` to a class which I don't have source code control over. I've tried:

```
class MyClass {} // class I'm not allowed to edit

class MyCategory {

  static def methodMissing(MyClass self, String name, Object args) {
      "I was hoping this was called on a.nonexisting()"
  }

  static def test(MyClass self) {
      "test works"
  }
}

def a = new MyClass()

use(MyCategory) {
    println a.test()
    println a.nonexisting()    
}
```

But I still get a `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: MyClass.nonexisting() is applicable for argument types: () values: []`

Is it possible to add a **temporary** `methodMissing` to a class?

I was trying to avoid to mess with the meta class since that change will be global and non-reversible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Groovy in Action, 2nd Edition published in 2015:

> Category method names can well take the form of property accessors
>   (pretending property access), operator methods, and GroovyObject
>   methods. MOP hook methods (propertyMissing, methodMissing) **cannot be added through a category
>   class**. This is a restriction as of Groovy 2.4. The feature may become available in later versions.

So it's not possible to do it in 2.4.12,

The [release notes for Groovy 2.5](http://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-2.5.html) (still in development as 2017-11) don't mention any changes regarding this.

The [release notes for Groovy 2.6](http://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-2.6.html) don't mention it either.

And finally unfortunately the [release notes for Groovy 3.0](http://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-3.0.html) say nothing about `methodMissing`